# Union of a Set and an Interval

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do you find the union of a set and an interval?

Consider the following example:
**{1, 3, 4} ∪ (4, ∞)**

If I understand the concept correctly, the resulting set would contain the numbers **1**, **3**, **4**, as well as all the numbers from **4** to positive infinity.
 In case my understanding of the concept is correct, then what notation do I use to express the answer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the union as $\{1,3\}\cup [4,\infty)$ but it does not simplify more. 
Espacially you can not write this as an interval, what you might want.

Keep in mind that $(4,\infty)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}| 4<x\}$

Comment: I see, that makes sense as a separate answer. It's only a tad confusing as I'm to do further operations that include the answer. More specifically:
  **A ∩ (B ⋃ C) ∩ D**
Where,
  A = **[-3, 1]**
  B = **{1, 3, 4}**
  C = **(4, ∞)**
  D = **(-∞, 1]**

Not sure how to tackle it when the answer to **B ⋃ C** doesn't simplify any further.

Comment: Just free yourself from the thought, that the solution at the end has to be 'beautiful', and go ahead like above. It might help, if you convert your intervals into sets, like I did above.